# Software flashes just a split second in taskbar. How to find out what software it is?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, flashing

I've started to notice a strange program that just flashes about every minute in my taskbar. I've uninstalled any strange software trough Windows Add or Remove Programs. It's quite annoying.

And my question is if it's there a software that can log or record processes that start and quit. I've tried to do this with Microsoft Process Monitor - procmon.exe, but there is no hope finding what I want.

Screen shot of the taskbar icon:

[image: icon]

Comment: ProcMon will help with this..  Exactly what did you try with ProcMon?

Comment: Captured processes until software flashed again, then searching stop the capturing and search for any suspicious process. But I didn't find nothing. Is there an alternative to ProcMon?

Comment: The icons resembles a small printer. It reminds me of the [Interactive Services Detection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/04/27/what-is-interactive-services-detection-and-why-is-it-blinking-at-me.aspx) program, `UI0Detect.exe`, which has [this icon](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DvCiH.png).

Comment: @and31415 , Yes the icon was from the Interactive Services Detecion. I'll describe the problem I have in my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) can achieve this:

Set the filter to "Operation is 'Process Create'" and "Operation is 'Process Start'" and watch events coming in:
[image: Instructions for using Process Monitor]

A more complicated way to do this is to use the Group Policy editor and then activate "[process auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941613%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)", but that's a bit more complicated than just using Process Monitor.

Comment: Helped me a lot :)! Find out that I didn't know to use this program. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The problem was caused by a software by Huawei Mobile Partner (DiGi Net Mobile - my version), controller for my internet stick from my ISP. First of all `RunLiveUpd.exe` is the cause, I think triggering Interactive Services Detecion - `UI0Detect.exe` showing the icon in taskbar for a short amount of time.

Here is the screen shot of Process Monitor showing the processes that started:
[image: Screenshot of Process Monitor]
Finally I've chosen to reinstall DiGi Net Mobile, and the problem disappeared. Certainly this is some sort of a bug.